# Gradient text on button without losing background color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a button that has a linear gradient only in the text, but when I make the button it loses the backgroud, can anyone help me?

https://codepen.io/caiohaffs/pen/wvXWBOZ

```css
button.default {
  width: 154px;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(65deg, #ff8d4d 0%, #6d37ff 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: 1.28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
}

button.default:hover {
  background: #FF8D4D;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF8D4D 0%, #6d37ff 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="default">Saiba Mais</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a pseudo element to keep the background color `#000`:

```css
button.default {
  width: 154px;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(65deg, #ff8d4d 0%, #6d37ff 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: 1.28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  /* ADDED LINE */
  position: relative;
}

button.default:hover {
  background: #FF8D4D;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF8D4D 0%, #6d37ff 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* ADDED */
button.default::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="default">Saiba Mais</button>
```

The CSS sets the `z-index: -1` to it displays below the parent element and also uses `pointer-events: none` to avoid the element from interfering with the `hover` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background where you also need two background-clip

```css
button.default {
  width: 154px;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(65deg, #ff8d4d 0%, #6d37ff 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, #FF8D4D 0%, #6d37ff 100%),
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: text, padding-box;
          background-clip: text, padding-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: 1.28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
}

button.default:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="default">Saiba Mais</button>
```

Comment: Looks like Firefox doesn't support the multi-background-clip `background-clip: text, anything-but-text`... Found it, it's https://bugzil.la/1481498